# PostgreSQL / Hive join multiple tables

Tags: postgresql, join, hive, left-join

Table a:

```
     id   value0
     101  a1
     102  a2
     103  a3
```

Table b:

```
     id  value1
     101  b1
     101  b2
     101  b3
```

Table c:

```
     id  value2
     101  c1
     103  c3
     103  c4
```

Rezult table:

```
     id value0 value1 value2
     101 a1    b1     0  
     101 a1    b2     0  
     101 a1    b3     0  
     101 a1    0      c1 
     102 a2    0      0
     103 a3    0      c3
     103 a3    0      c4
```

Is it possible to produce rezult table from tables a, b, c with one query (without creating two tables and join them)? Maybe there is a possibility to do it by using only left joins?

Answer (score 0):

This may help you-

```
    select t1.id, t2.id, t3.id
    from tablea t1 inner join tableb t2 on t1.id = t2.id
    inner join tablec t3 on t2.id=t3.id
    group by id
```

Comment: Sorry, I've mislead you. I add one more row to table a(102  a2).

Answer (score 0):

If you have a base table, select that and do a `left join` to the others. If none of your tables can act as a base table, you can use `full join`s (both works as [outer joins](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/queries-table-expressions.html#QUERIES-JOIN)):

```
select    *
from      table_a
full join table_b using (id)
full join table_c using (id)
```

This will select sql `NULL`s, where there is no data, but you can use `COLAESCE(value0, 'N/A')`, etc. to select some default data.